# escaping quotes issue

Tags: javascript, quotes

in PHP I create this object that I convert to JSON and send to a JS client:

```
$arr = array("img"=>"http://www.myDomain.com/imgs/pic_1.jpg","data"=>"<p>This is a paragraph <a href='#' onclick='MyFunction('myParameter');'>My Link</a></p>");
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with quotes (check the function call) but at the moment, once injected in my HTML, MyFunction never gets called. Which is the right way to escape quotes in that situation?

**EDIT**: this is the resulting JSON:

```
{"img":"http:\/\/www.myDomain.com\/imgs\/pic_1.jpg","data":"<p>Paragraph: <a href='#' onclick='localFunction('parameter');'>Link<\/a><\/p>","length":2}
```

Comment: How does the resulting JS look like? What are you doing with the data?

Comment: What object? This is an array. You also omit the most relevant piece of code: the JSON conversion. Not to mention that JSON is not JavaScript: it cannot contain code.

Comment: @DonCallisto: that makes no sense and also is false.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: if we assume he's using the builtin JSON conversion tools, then that's a non-issue. It's also a non-issue because the issue is evident in the code she *did* give.

Comment: @Len - You are right. The question is not related to neither PHP nor JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='#' onclick='MyFunction('myParameter');'>
```

You have single quotes inside "onclick" but "onclick" itself is delimited with single quotes.

Try:

```
$arr = array("img"=>"http://www.myDomain.com/imgs/pic_1.jpg","data"=>"<p>This is a paragraph <a href='#' onclick=\"MyFunction('myParameter');\">My Link</a></p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a faulty nesting of quotes in `onclick='MyFunction('myParameter');'`. Use escaped double quotes instead:

```
onclick=\"MyFunction('myParameter');\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mention of JSON is a red herring.

Look at the code. I have marked the start and end of the attribute value:

```
 onclick='MyFunction('myParameter');'>
         ^           ^
```

You either need to use different quotes, which have to be escaped because they are inside a PHP string delimited by that type of quote:

```
 onclick='MyFunction(\"myParameter\");'>
```

… or you need to use HTML entities:

```
 onclick='MyFunction(&quot;myParameter&quot;);'>
```

---

Generally speaking though, you should avoid intrinsic event attributes entirely and favour JavaScript event binding instead (often with event delegation so you don't need to bind events every time you add new elements to the DOM).